# Completely unresponsive desktop in 15.10 when running Transmission

Tags: crash, transmission

I've been having this problem in Ubuntu 15.10 where almost every day, my desktop becomes 100% unresponsive. The laptop won't sleep when the lid is closed, I can't switch TTY, I can't even use Alt+SysRq+REISUB. The only solution is to hold down the power button and force the system to shutdown.

I've narrowed the problem down and found that it only freezes when I have Transmission running. It freezes regardless of how many torrents are currently running and it seems to happen completely at random - not just when the system is under stress. I have never had this problem with any other distro. I've done several clean reinstalls, and this problem happens whatever filesystem or I/O scheduler I use.

My laptop is a ThinkPad X240, with an i5 processor, 4GB of RAM and a 1TB HDD. I would really appreciate any help, since this is kind of a show stopping issue, and I don't want to have to move away from Ubuntu since I am so happy with everything else. I would like to file a bug report, but I'm not sure what to submit. I will post the output of anything you want.

Comment: Another torrent client? Try deluge. Possibly hard disc failure - run chkdsk or some other tool. Is your laptop connected by wireless or ethernet? try another way. This is how I'd debug this.

Comment: Also, don't you have any unusual messages in console\logs when it happens?

Comment: Can't do chkdsk since that's a Windows utility, but I ran "sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda1 > bad-blocks-result"  - 0 bad blocks found. Could try Deluge I suppose, I've used it before and I've never had a problem with it, though I tend to prefer Transmission on GTK3 environments.

Comment: I want to be clear that this doesn't happen instantly upon opening Transmission, sometimes, several hours pass before I get a complete freeze. All I can say for sure is that I was having complete lockups on a near-daily basis, then stopped using transmission for a week and didn't experience a single failure. Then after running Transmission for a few hours, Ubuntu locked up. I was advised that it might be an IO issue - but top and iotop don't report anything particularly odd.

Comment: One time, I was lucky enough to have iotop and System Monitor on screen, but I was using the workspace expo when it happened so it was very small. I could see that at least 2 cores were maxed out on the monitor, and on iotop, a kworker process was showing 99.9% IO. As for the logs - I'm not sure where to look, since /var/log/messages doesn't exist. Happy to post output of any command you think will help.

Comment: I'm very interested in this issue because I had similar experience. In the end I solved it, but I don't know how. Replaced hdd with ssd, upgraded to 15.04, removed Intel processor driver, also winter is here and it's much cooler now.

Comment: Did you ever try another bittorrent client? (qBittorrent is the one I can help you with...)